# Remap data from Polar Stereographic projection to Lat-Lon

Tags: python, gdal, netcdf, cdo-climate, pyproj

I have a NetCDF file with storm track density data over south polar stereographic projection. Both X and Y coordinates range from -1.924274 to 1.88504 (I don't know the units here). The link for the .nc file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DSDIIlWgxlOF9snISntz7_1IVYf5ySbJ/view?usp=sharing).

When I open the file with Xarray and plot the data, I have the following:
[image]

Is there any way to remap this to lat-lon grid in Python or CDO?
Thanks!

Comment: You could try rioxarray: https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/reproject.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably do this using my package nctoolkit (https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which uses CDO as a back end.

```
import nctoolkit as nc
data = nc.open_data("infile.nc")
data.to_latlon(lon = [lon_min, lon_max], lat = [lat_min, lat_max])
data.plot()
```

You will need to define lon_min etc.

Comment: I had to make some adjustments to my data, but it worked, thanks!